# Fetch the latest build number which is successful from azure devops using powershell

Tags: powershell

Using the following script I am getting the build information from the pipeline and want to extract the latest build number which is succeed,

```
function fetchBuildNumber() {
        $pat ="<personal acess token>"
        $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)")) }
        $UriOrganization = "https://<rest_api>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7"  
        $ProjectsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UriOrganization -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
    
        Foreach ($buildResult in $ProjectsResult.value.result) {
            if ($buildResult.equals("succeeded")){
                Write-Host $ProjectsResult.value.buildNumber
             }
        }
    }
    
    fetchBuildNumber
```

I am getting the below result,

```
@{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=223567; buildNumber=20231016.1; status=completed; result=succeeded; queueTime=2023-10-16T06:23:50.9273616Z; startTime=2023-10-16T06:23:58.4673447Z; finishTime=2023-10-16T06:24:10.4163032Z; url=https://<url>/<project>/b9f9d6e9-a99a-4c65-9c44-adf670a6fff3/_apis/build/Builds/223567; definition=; buildNumberRevision=1; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/223567; sourceBranch=refs/heads/master; sourceVersion=959c15fdf53e30a60ab9f1f95f050c07380248d6; queue=; priority=normal; reason=individualCI; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2023-10-16T06:24:10.81Z; lastChangedBy=; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; retainedByRelease=False; triggeredByBuild=; appendCommitMessageToRunName=True} @{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=223566; buildNumber=20231016.5; status=completed; result=failed; queueTime=2023-10-16T06:22:53.8662857Z; startTime=2023-10-16T06:23:01.2164532Z; finishTime=2023-10-16T06:23:16.1320749Z; url=https://<url>/<project>/b9f9d6e9-a99a-4c65-9c44-adf670a6fff3/_apis/build/Builds/223566; definition=; buildNumberRevision=5; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/223566; sourceBranch=refs/heads/master; sourceVersion=482cfa62cea136463b7c8f10ccf174d9d78d7349; queue=; priority=normal; reason=individualCI; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2023-10-16T06:23:16.603Z; lastChangedBy=; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; retainedByRelease=False; triggeredByBuild=; appendCommitMessageToRunName=True} @{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=223556; buildNumber=20231016.4; status=completed; result=failed; queueTime=2023-10-16T05:44:36.5531704Z; startTime=2023-10-16T05:44:43.9888586Z; finishTime=2023-10-16T05:45:00.6769804Z; url=https://<url>/<project>/b9f9d6e9-a99a-4c65-9c44-adf670a6fff3/_apis/build/Builds/223556; definition=; buildNumberRevision=4; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/223556; sourceBranch=refs/heads/master; sourceVersion=7c3708310a88b1074c5f455dd0a896ee2c532cf0; queue=; priority=normal; reason=manual; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2023-10-16T05:45:00.933Z; lastChangedBy=; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; retainedByRelease=False; triggeredByBuild=; appendCommitMessageToRunName=True} @{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=223555; buildNumber=20231016.3; status=completed; result=failed; queueTime=2023-10-16T05:44:30.908171Z; startTime=2023-10-16T05:44:37.2857315Z; finishTime=2023-10-16T05:44:50.3619703Z; url=https://<url>/<project>/b9f9d6e9-a99a-4c65-9c44-adf670a6fff3/_apis/build/Builds/223555; definition=; buildNumberRevision=3; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/223555; sourceBranch=refs/heads/master; sourceVersion=7c3708310a88b1074c5f455dd0a896ee2c532cf0; queue=; priority=normal; reason=individualCI; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2023-10-16T05:44:50.69Z; lastChangedBy=; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; retainedByRelease=False; triggeredByBuild=; appendCommitMessageToRunName=True} @{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=223552; buildNumber=20231016.2; status=completed; result=succeeded; queueTime=2023-10-16T05:38:42.0775965Z; startTime=2023-10-16T05:38:49.9645514Z; finishTime=2023-10-16T05:39:00.9177615Z; url=https://<url>/<project>/b9f9d6e9-a99a-4c65-9c44-adf670a6fff3/_apis/build/Builds/223552; definition=; buildNumberRevision=2; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/223552; sourceBranch=refs/heads/master; sourceVersion=01eae21771b801f4593aaf2605a017c86b93f45c; queue=; priority=normal; reason=individualCI; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2023-10-16T05:39:01.27Z; lastChangedBy=; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; retainedByRelease=False; triggeredByBuild=; appendCommitMessageToRunName=True} @{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=223551; buildNumber=20231016.1; status=completed; result=succeeded; queueTime=2023-10-16T05:37:38.8167652Z; startTime=2023-10-16T05:37:46.3075953Z; finishTime=2023-10-16T05:37:58.4518333Z; url=https://<url>/<project>/b9f9d6e9-a99a-4c65-9c44-adf670a6fff3/_apis/build/Builds/223551; definition=; buildNumberRevision=1; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/223551; sourceBranch=refs/heads/master; sourceVersion=1d793ebd727867f1f0dfa76a569c593463236ce9; queue=; priority=normal; reason=individualCI; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2023-10-16T05:37:58.893Z; lastChangedBy=; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; retainedByRelease=False; triggeredByBuild=; appendCommitMessageToRunName=True}
```

How to fetch the latest build number which is succeeded (which is `"20231016.5"`) what changes required in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason yours doesn't work is due to the foreach loop. You're looping through each result and if it succeeds, you're outputting the entire $ProjectsResult.value.buildnumber each time, not just that specific build result.

Replace

```
Foreach ($buildResult in $ProjectsResult.value.result) {
            if ($buildResult.equals("succeeded")){
                Write-Host $ProjectsResult.value.buildNumber
             }
        }
```

with

```
$ProjectsResult.value | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.result -eq 'succeeded') {
        Write-Host $_.buildNumber
    }
}
```